# How to get controls from panel in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well, I am doing a project on online movie ticket booking.

My problem is, I want to show the seating arrangement in a screen of a particular theater.

As in every row the number of seats can vary so what I have done is add a panel and in it a checkboxlist is dynamically added during runtime.

each checkboxlist represents a single row.

```
string s;

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["row_id_no_of_seats"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cbl = new CheckBoxList();
    cbl.RepeatDirection = 0; //horizontal
    cbl.RepeatLayout = 0; //table
    cbl.RepeatColumns = (int)ds.Tables["row_id_no_of_seats"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cbl);

    for(int j=1;j<=(int)ds.Tables["row_id_no_of_seats"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1];j++)
    {
         s = ds.Tables["row_id_no_of_seats"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() + j.ToString(); //ex:A+1
         cbl.Items.Add(s);

         string query1 = "select booking_detail.row_id,booking_detail.column_id from booking_detail,booking where (booking_detail.booking_id=booking.booking_id) and (booking_detail.booking_date='" + bk_date + "') and (booking.booking_date='" + bk_date + "') and (booking.theatre_id=" + theatre_id + ") and (booking.screen_id=" + screen_id + ") and (booking.movie_id=" + movie_id + ") and (booking.show_start_time='" + show_start_time + "') and (booking.class_id=" + class_id + ")";

         SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);

         adapter.SelectCommand = command1;
         adapter.Fill(ds, "seat_booked_info");

         // it checks and disables  the seats which have been pre- booked.
         for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables["seat_booked_info"].Rows.Count;k++) {
             if(ds.Tables["seat_booked_info"].Rows[k].ItemArray[0].ToString().Equals(ds.Tables["row_id_no_of_seats"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString())) && (ds.Tables["seat_booked_info"].Rows[k].ItemArray[1].ToString().Equals(j.ToString())))
             {
                 cbl.Items.FindByText(s).Selected=true;        
                 cbl.Items.FindByText(s).Enabled = false;

             }
         }
         ds.Tables["seat_booked_info"].Clear();
    }
}
```

Now what I want is, how do I get the details of the checkbox which have been selected by the user as the checkboxlist are dynamically added to the panel?

Comment: You should check your keyboard. It seems your Caps lock key is active...

Comment: You should read up on sql injection as well, which your code might be vulnerable to, depending on the variables you are using in the query statement. It's usually better to use parameters, which makes the code more maintainable as well.

Comment: thanks for the advice sir ,..i'll definately make the necessary changes..but sir do you have any sollution to my problem....

Answer (score 1):

You would use something like this:

```
foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls)
{
    CheckBoxList list = c as CheckBoxList;

    if (c != null)
    {
        // Do something with the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont check with `is` and then use `as`. If you're not interested in the code throwing an InvalidCastException, just use `as` and check for `null`.

Comment: @Patrick -- you are absolutely right. I just changed my code to reflect your suggestion.